# How to add a Google Sign-in functionality in Chrome extension with firebase or without firebase auth using the latest version Chrome extension MV3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-signin

I want to allow users to sign-in in my chrome extension with the help of Google Sign-in button in latest version MV3 and I have tried out many approaches but still not getting the results.

I have tried out the code with MV2 but they are deprecated now